# ARRAYFORMULA for a column, but only for blank cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm trying to fill a formula down a column using `ARRAYFORMULA`. However, there are certain cells in this column which I would like to overwrite, but all the other cells should use the `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Is it possible to use `ARRAYFORMULA` with overrides? Whenever I try to override a cell's data currently in the column, I get the following error:

> Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in (some cell).

Comment: not sure what exactly you want to accomplish... you want to override only certain cells in selected range of array? if so then thats not possible.

Comment: I think so... I want to expand the array formula in column C, let's say, but I want to add custom values to C2, C8, and C10. However, I want the other cells (i.e. the ones other than C2, C8, and C10) to keep using the array formula

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet or arrayformula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in (**some cell**).

this error indicates that **some cell** isn't empty therefore array won't be executed on a given range/scale. your options are:

- delete the content of **some cell**
- use multiple ranges in the array formula to skip excluded cells 
  **`=ARRAYFORMULA({C1;C3:C7;C9:C})`**
- use array formula 3 times in **C1**, **C3** and **C9**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is not an option for me because I'm using the array formula as a sort of "default value" unfortunately, but it seems like it won't be possible from this